# Copying the contents of an H2 tag on a page to a series of spans inside a div

Tags: jquery

I have an H1 tag on a page with an ID of "Topic Name

```
<h1 id="topicName"><a href="/link here">News You Can Use</a></h1>
```

I need to copy the text inside the H1 and apply it to a series of span tags which are inside a div.

```
<div class="post"> <h2>{tag_postdate} <span class="topicName2"> </span></h2></div>
```

I need to get "News you can Use" and copy it inside each instance of .topicName2

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
$('.topicName2').text($('#topicName').text());
```

Reference: [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)